# Data object consistency with several workers node

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, cluster-computing

I am trying to create a simple server which will give every new request to different worker. The `DATA object` is a simple javascript object in separate file. The problem I faced with is CONSISTENCY of this `DATA object`.

How to prevent worker from handling the request if the previous request is still proceeding? 
 For example first request is `UPDATE` and lasts longer and the next request is `DELETE` and proceeds faster 
 What node tool or pattern I need to use to be 100% percent sure that `DELETE` will happen after `UPDATE`? 
I need to run every worker on a different port

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

cluster.schedulingPolicy = cluster.SCHED_RR;

const PORT = 4000; 

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
 http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if(req.url === '/users' && req.method === "PUT") {
       updateUser(req)
    } else if(req.url === '/users' && req.method === "DELETE") {
       deleteUser(req)
    } 

  }).listen(PORT++);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't even create multiple servers set aside the different ports, and the PORT variable is a `const`, so it won't increment either.

> What node tool or pattern I need to use to be 100% percent sure that DELETE will happen after UPDATE?

- Use some sort of [lock](https://w3c.github.io/web-locks/), not yet available on JavaScript
- Use a semaphore/Mutex variable lock (See code).

Remember, JavaScript is a single-threaded language.

> need to run every worker on a different port

For each worker, set the listening based on worker ID (See code). Remember that the CPU cannot have capability to generate workers equal to that of number of cores.

Sample working code:

```js
const express = require('express')
const cluster = require('cluster')
const os = require('os')

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (let i = 0; i < os.cpus().length; i++) {
        cluster.fork()
    }
} else {
    const app = express()

    // Global semaphore/mutex variable isUpdating
    var isUpdating = false;
    const worker = {
        handleRequest(req, res) {
            console.log("handleRequest on worker /" + cluster.worker.id);
            if (req.method == "GET") { // FOR BROWSER TESTING, CHANGE IT LATER TO PUT
                isUpdating = true;
                console.log("updateUser GET");
                // do updateUser(req);
                isUpdating = false;
            } else if (req.method == "DELETE") {
                if (!isUpdating) { // Check for update lock
                    console.log("updateUser DELETE");
                    // do deleteUser(req)
                }
            }
        },
    }

    app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
        worker.handleRequest(req, res)
    })

    // Now each worker will run on different port
    app.listen(4000 + cluster.worker.id, () => {
        console.log(`Worker ${cluster.worker.id} started listening on port ${4000 + cluster.worker.id}`)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. May you also take a look on another example? Maybe you know how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74778007/node-simple-cluster-but-workers-have-different-ports

Comment: I'll see. Please accept this and upvote, if useful, sincere request.

Answer (score 1):

Each worker must reserve ("lock") the DATA object for exclusive use before it can change it. This can be done by writing a lock file and deleting it again after successful object change.

```js
try {
  fs.openSync("path/to/lock/file", "wx+");
  /* Change DATA object */
  fs.rmSync("path/to/lock/file");
} catch(err) {
  if (err.code === "EEXIST") throw "locking conflict";
}
```

The worker executing the first (UPDATE) request will succeed in writing the lock file, but a concurrent worker executing a second (DELETE) request will experience a locking conflict. It can then either report the failure to the user, or re-try after a short waiting time.

(If you decide to implement the lock in this way, the asynchronous [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/fs.html) methods may be more efficient.)