# Node simple cluster but workers have different ports

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, cluster-computing

I'm trying to implement the following:

- server listens `5000 port` and when receives requests - sends them to cluster workers
- several cluster workers run on `5001, 5002, ...` ports, proceed requests and send responses to the client
- worker should work with the same instance of in-memory-db (array `postsDB`)
- so if first worker receives `POST request` and second worker receives `GET request` - they change data in the same array

I'm using cluster hoping that it will distribute requests for workers using built-in Round-Robin Algorithm

But at the moment I don't understand how I can emit `request` received from process inside `worker_CRUD_server`.
Also I am not sure if they would use only on instance of in-memory DB

```
const cluster = require("cluster");
const http = require("http");
const os = require("os");
let port = 5000;
const server = http.createServer().listen(port);

const postsDB = [{ title: "First Post" }, { title: "Second Post" }];

if (cluster.isPrimary) {
  for (let i = 0; i < os.cpus().length - 1; i++) {
    server.on("connect", (req) => {
      const worker = cluster.fork();
      worker.send(req);
    });
  }
}

if (cluster.isWorker) {
  const worker_CRUD_server = http
    .createServer(/* hadling requests and sending responses - CRUD with postsDB*/)
    .listen(++port);

  process.on("message", (req) => {
    /* somehow send req to worker_CRUD_server and invoke proceeding request and sending response to client?? */
  });
}
```

From documentation example I understand that it's more simple to run workers on the same PORT, but I need to implement this as I described - Main port sends tasks to worker ports.

Comment: This is not what the cluster module is made for at all.  If you want separate servers running on separate ports in separate threads/processes, then just use either WorkerThreads or child_process to start up separate servers - no reason for the cluster module.  Or, if you just want multiple servers in your one process, just start up multiple servers, each on its own port in your own code - again no need for the cluster module.  The purpose of the cluster module is to load balance (to separate processes) incoming requests all arriving on the same port.  That's what it does.

Comment: @jfriend00 But if I need main server for distributing requests across child processes on different ports - how can I redirect them from main thread using pure node.js?

Comment: Why does the main server need to distribute requests if they're all on different ports?   Just fire up more http servers, either in the same process or in child processes processes and let each process handle its own requests.  The cluster module does not do what you want here.  The cluster module does round robin distribution from ONE server on ONE port.

Comment: And, if the main server did for some reason need to handle all incoming requests, then you'd start up all the http servers in the main process (so its listening for all the incoming traffic) and then forward the requests to child processes for processing (either coded manually or using a proxy library).

Comment: Also, multiple processes will likely not be directly accessing the same memory.  You can use an in-memory database that supports a TCP/HTTP interface (like Redis) so all the procesess can communicate with that in-memory database.

Comment: Why do you need separate ports?  Why not just use the cluster module as it was intended?  One incoming port and requests are round-robin distributed to the clustered processes.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanations. It became more clear. Answering your question: in kind of "bootcamp" materials I have found this task. And it should be implemented as described: pure node.js and data - simple js array.